# Convert existing asp.net application (large) to web standards

Tags: asp.net, web-standards

I have a very large ASP.NET project that i need to make good with web standards -- the application has two parts:
1.) An administrative piece that allows users to 'build' sites
2.) Front end that makes up the users sites (many web controls, master pages, usercontrols, etc... much of it is just code)

I was wondering what poeples recomendations are for making this project utilize web standards?  Should i look more into MVC?  I havent done anything with MVC but it seems to support friendly URL's by default.

Has anyone done this with an existing large ASP.NET application/site?

thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two routes you can take.

1) Rip it up and start again
2) Modify what you have and incrementally change it 'one page at a time'

I know that's a simple and obvious answer but truthfully, having done both, they are both viable.

A modern ASP.NET web applciation *CAN* be standards compliant, can have nice urls with some url re-writing and can seperate content from design. You just need to think before you act, make sure you use .NET 2.0 or .NET 3.5 controls and inspect the output to ensure you're getting good markup.

Converting an old web app to MVC can;'t really be answered without knowing the app itself. It might be perfectly suited to it and be easy, it might be a world of pain.

As always use the best tool for the job.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by web standards? Valid html/css? no-tale layout? valid javascript?

I suggest you just test it in different browsers and fix the problems you find.